# How to change the button color and status based on condition in angular?

Tags: angular

HTML(In this, I need to button status based on quantity received and totalqty,
   for that, I have written if-else condition to display the button... 
   here I have written some logic...
   but this is not working properly.. could you help??)

```
<div style="border-radius: 10px;margin-top: 7px;">
    <span *ngIf="red" class="btn btn-danger">No Receipt</span>
    <span *ngIf="yellow" class="btn btn-warning">Partial Receipt</span>
    <span *ngIf="green" class="btn btn-success">Completed</span> 
</div>
```

component.ts(In this, I need to button status based on quantity received and totalqty,
   for that, I have written if-else condition to display the button... 
   here I have written some logic...
   but this is not working properly.. could you help??)

```
red: false;
green: false;
yellow: false;
ngOnInit(){
    this.totalQty = result[0].POMaterials[0].quantity
    this.receivedQty = result[0].POMaterials[0].received_lots[0].qty_recieved
}
colorbuttons(){
    if(this.totalQty === this.receivedQty ){
        this.green = true;
    }
    else if(this.totalQty > this.receivedQty){
        this.yellow = true;
    }
    else{
        this.red = true;
    } 
}
```

Comment: Have you tried debugging your code and seeing what happens inside colobuttons? When is colobuttons called?

Comment: What do you mean by "not working properly" ? Please note that `colorButtons()` function is never called.

Comment: i have called colorButtons() function in my code. i forgot to mention it here..

Answer (score 1):

Okay so first of all, your code is not working because you confused type (`red: boolean`) and assignment (`red = true`).
Then, as I mention before, I don't see a call for `colorButtons()` function

In order to make it work, update your code like this :

```js
  totalQty = 50;
  receivedQty = 30;

  className: string;
  label: string;

  ngOnInit(){
    this.colorButtons();
  }

  colorButtons(){
    if (this.totalQty === this.receivedQty ){
      this.className = 'btn-success';
      this.label = 'Completed';
    } else if (this.totalQty > this.receivedQty){
      this.className = 'btn-warning';
      this.label = 'Partial Receipt';
    } else{// my 3rd condition is this.receivedqty === 0 (how do i achieve this??)
      this.className = 'btn-danger';
      this.label = 'No Receipt';
    } 
  }
```

HTML part is a little bit different :

```html
<div style="border-radius: 10px; margin-top: 7px;">
  <span [class]="'btn' + ' ' + className">{{ label }}</span>
</div>
```

I made a Stackblitz [just here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-nexsly)

**EDIT 1**

I update my code. It's better to manage CSS classes into HTML file.

Are you looking for something like this ?

state.enum.ts

```js
export enum State {
  Success,
  Warning,
  Error
}
```

app.component.ts

```js
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { State } from './state.enum';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: [ './app.component.css' ]
})
export class AppComponent  {
  totalQty = 50;
  receivedQty = 0;
  State = State;

  get state(): State {
    if (this.receivedQty === 0) {
      return State.Error
    }

    if (this.totalQty > this.receivedQty) {
      return State.Warning
    }

    if (this.totalQty === this.receivedQty) {
      return State.Success
    }
    return null
  }
}
```

app.component.html

```html
<div style="border-radius: 10px; margin-top: 7px;" [ngSwitch]="state">
  <span *ngSwitchCase="State.Success" class="btn btn-success">Completed</span>
  <span *ngSwitchCase="State.Warning" class="btn btn-warning">Partial Receipt</span>
  <span *ngSwitchCase="State.Error" class="btn btn-danger">No Receipt</span>
  <span *ngSwitchDefault class="btn btn-danger" disabled>Unknown</span>
</div>

<button (click)="receivedQty = 0">0</button>
<button (click)="receivedQty = 10">10</button>
<button (click)="receivedQty = totalQty">Max</button>
```

Comment: @Rekha is this what you were looking for ?

Comment: Then one more thing i would like to know... if I have more than one received qty, i have to add those qty then need to campare with totalqty... How can i do this??

Comment: this.receivedQty = result[0].POMaterials[0].received_lots[0].qty_recieved ;   here i am getting received_lots [0] this is only for 1st array.. If i have more than one array means i need to get both array qty_received then add both the values and compare with total quantity.. could you possibly do this??could you create stackblitz for this??

Answer (score 0):

just change some snippets of your code like below:

```
red = false;
green = false;
yellow = false;
ngOnInit(){
    this.totalQty = result[0].POMaterials[0].quantity
    this.receivedQty = result[0].POMaterials[0].received_lots[0].qty_recieved
}
colorbuttons(){
    if(this.totalQty === this.receivedQty ){
        this.yellow = false;
        this.red = false;
        this.green = true;
    }
    else if(this.totalQty > this.receivedQty){
        this.green = false;
        this.red = false;
        this.yellow = true;
    }
    else{
        this.green = false;
        this.yellow = false;
        this.red = true;
    } 
}
```